# JPA entity classes are not discovered automatically with Gradle

Tags: java, jpa, gradle

I'm new to Gradle. I'm trying to run some tests but they fail with messages showing that the entity classes are not mapped. When I explicitly map the classes in *persistence.xml* everything works fine. I did some research and found that adding theses lines to the build script would solve the problem:

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
```

but it simply didn't work for me. I still get the errors if I don't specify the classes in the deployment descriptor.

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

My project structure:

[image: My project structure]

My *persistence.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bd">
        <class>br.desenvolvimento.teste.modelo.Cliente</class>
        <class>br.desenvolvimento.teste.modelo.Banco</class>
        <class>br.desenvolvimento.teste.modelo.AgenciaBancaria</class>
        <class>br.desenvolvimento.teste.modelo.ContaBancaria</class>
        <class>br.desenvolvimento.teste.modelo.Filho</class>
        <class>br.desenvolvimento.teste.modelo.Projeto</class>
        <class>br.desenvolvimento.teste.modelo.Telefone</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Is that project hosted online?

Comment: How do you start JPA in your tests? Are you running something like PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory or you are running the tests using Arquillian inside an application server?

Comment: @Opal the project is not hosted online. @OndrejM The project is a Java SE project. I don't use _Arquillian_. I start JPA using `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have to use this friggin' gradle and have exactly the same problem. Works only with definition in persistence.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Which Gradle version do you use? If it is 5.x, you need to update your lines like the following:

```
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.java.outputDir
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.java.outputDir
```

Your `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir` is deprecated on Gradle 4.x and withdrawed on Gradle 5.x.

In my case, a portion of `build.gradle` is the following:

```
sourceSets {
  java {
    main {
      output.resourcesDir = java.outputDir
    }
  }
}
```

See: SourceSetOutput - Gradle DSL Version 5.5 https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and adding the

```
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
```

line fixed the problem for me (only this line needed). So thank you for your tip :)

I have a same project structure as yours so I don't know why this not works for you.

Comment: Doesn't work for me neither. Same problem as the OP.